# Inferred type does not match expected type (IO a) with splitOn

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use `splitOn` function in haskell to split a string based on some delimiters. So the splitOn function returns data of type `[[Char]]`, but the compiler is showing error saying that the expected type is `IO a`.

The line of code which is failing is:

```
splitOn "x" "1 2, 3"
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've written something like `xs <- splitOn "x" line` and simply want to bind a name to `splitOn "x" line`, then you can use `let xs = splitOn "x" line`. `<-` is for binding values from IO actions, rather than assigning names to pure values.

Otherwise, you've presumably done something like this:

```
main = do
  line <- getLine
  splitOn "x" line
```

You're using a `[String]`, but you need an IO action. You need to *do* something with the pure result you've got to turn it into an IO computation.

You could print the list out, as GHCi would:

```
print :: (Show a) => a -> IO ()
```

Or you could use `return`, if you simply want to return the pure computation to be used in other IO actions:

```
return :: a -> IO a
```

It all depends on how you want to process the data.

Comment: can you tell me how do i print this list.its a [[char]].i am storing it as let xs =splitOn "x" line Thanks

Comment: @guarav: Well, that depends on how you want the result to look like. If you want elements of the list on separate lines, you can do `putStr (unlines xs)` (`unlines` is inverse of `lines`, i.e. it takes `[String]`, inserts `\n` between the elements and then flattens it to `String`), or `mapM_ putStrLn xs`; if you want to print it as a list (i.e. `["Hello","world"]`), you can just use `print xs`.

Comment: @guarav: You're welcome! If you accept my answer, it'll help others who find this question in the future, too.